# fail2ban won't work

Tags: 14.04, server, iptables, fail2ban

A few days ago I setup a new whole Server (Mailserver with Zarafa / Postfix, Apache, MySQL, and so on). Everything works fine.. except fail2ban. Fail2ban do nothing. He don't even act if something is happened.

This is the log for my fail2ban: http://pastebin.com/9jj7JWxA

This is my jail.local file: http://pastebin.com/YgcmpukT

And this is the output for `iptables -S`:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N fail2ban-apache
-N fail2ban-postfix
-N fail2ban-sasl
-N fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587,143,220,993,110,995 -j fail2ban-sasl
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -j fail2ban-postfix
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-apache
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A fail2ban-apache -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-postfix -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-sasl -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
```

Has someone an idea why fail2ban just do nothing?

Comment: what makes you think it is not working ?

Comment: Because I tested it by myself to get banned for invalid logins and nothing happens (and do way more invalid logins as the jail.local says what is required)? What kind of question is this... I know it is not working actual.

Comment: How does the route.conf look?  fail2ban is set to route instead of using iptables - jail.local line 72

Comment: Configure fail2ban to use route instead of iptables to block connections
 http://www.faqforge.com/linux/controlpanels/ispconfig3/configure-fail2ban-to-use-route-instead-of-iptables-to-block-connections/

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by 'apt-get remove fail2ban' v.0.8.11 and manually install newest fail2ban v.0.9.4 from github.

Exactly that new package got better filter.d for all the new error messages from Ubuntu 14.04.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Your *iptables -S* output shows, that fail2ban has created some chains but no ips have been added so far to those chains.

The links to your logfile and jail.conf aren't valid anymore.

I would check those possible issues:

- your jails look at the correct log files
- your jails look for the right port/protocol
- your filter use the correct failregex for your protocol format
- your banaction is adding ips to iptables chains correctly